# I want to when you click the textbox twice to become available for modification

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>

    function myFunction(id) {

    if (document.getElementById(id).hasAttribute("disabled"))
    { 
     document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    }

</script>



<input id="demo" disabled="false"  ondblclick="myFunction(this:id)" value="Click me to change disabled.">
```

I want to when you click the textbox twice to become available for modification .
Please do not work has a solution Click me to change disabled I have used the removeAttributeto clear disabled but it did not work and thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Disabled elements don't fire mouse events.

Comment: this:id?  I think you need to brush up on your javascript syntax

Comment: I want to when you click the textbox twice to become available for modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to remove the disabled attribute on click.

One common mistake is to attach events to disabled elements. Most browsers won't call the events, as the elements are disabled, so you must listen for an ancestor and do some logic for it to work.

Check this. I've attached it to the body and detect the target of the event:

```js
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "demo" && event.target.hasAttribute("disabled")) { 
        event.target.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="demo" disabled="false" value="Click me to change disabled.">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
<input id="demo" disabled="false"  onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Click me to change disabled.">

<script>

    function myFunction(box) {
        if (box.hasAttribute("disabled")) { 
           box.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }

</script>
```